# Java Click on a object and output a message

Tags: java

Im currently making a game in my spare time to improve my java but im having trouble with one of the things i want to do. Ive made the game so i can put a item into a certain position. In this example its a tower in a certain location. When this tower is placed in this location and i click on the tower i want it to output a message. However ive tried many ways to do this and i havent been able to find a solution. The code i have for this is:

```
public static void click(int X, int Y){
    System.out.println("X. " + X + " Y. " + Y);

    if(Screen.room.block[X][Y].airID == Value.tower){
        System.out.println("Tower clicked");
    }
}
```

When the tower is placed in a location the code i use for this is:

```
        if(holdsItem){
                for(int y=0; y<Screen.room.block.length; y++){
                    for(int x=0; x<Screen.room.block[0].length; x++){
                        if(Screen.room.block[y][x].contains(Screen.mse)){
                            if(Screen.room.block[y][x].groundID != Value.ground && Screen.room.block[y][x].airID == Value.tower){
                                Screen.room.block[y][x].airID = heldID;


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

When i put down a tower by:

```
System.out.println(Screen.room.block[y][x]);
```

i get

```
Block[x=243,y=260,width=52,height=52]
```

This works fine and the tower is placed. I then wanted to use the location of what the tower is placed and then if that location is pressed the message would print in the console. However this doesnt happen. Can anyone help me fix this problem.

I use a mouse listener which is:

```
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        e.getX();
        e.getY();
        Block.click(e.getX(), e.getY());

    }
```

When i click on a location i get:

```
System.out.println("X. " + X + " Y. " + Y);

X. 257 Y. 298
```

if this helps.

Comment: How are your items place on the parent container?  Are the custom painted or are they components?

Comment: It seems to me that you need to click on the *exact* pixel where the tower is for this to work. Am I reading this right? How big are the squares in this game?

Comment: what is the `Value.tower`? because it would give you an error if it's acessing the click method and didn't find the room in the x, y position

Comment: Is it possible for you to add a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) so we can get the context?

Comment: Value.tower is = 1. This is so it checks for the type of tower as there will be more than one type of tower. The square sizes are 50.

Comment: debug it and compare the values.. that is the only way to know what is really happening

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you are using pixels to get the location of your object, so you need to check more than the exact "origin" pixel for each block.

```
public static void click(int X, int Y){
    System.out.println("X. " + X + " Y. " + Y);

    //Look for every block in the matrix
    for ( int i = 0; i<Screen.room.block.length; i++ ) {
      for ( int j = 0; j<Screen.room.block[0].length; j++ ) {
         if(Screen.room.block[i][j].airID == Value.tower){
            //Check if we hit within the block's bounds
            if ( X >= i && X <= i+blockWidth &&
                 Y >= j && Y <= j+blockHeight  )
             System.out.println("Tower clicked");
             return;
         }
      }
    }
}
```

A common practice is to store your objects in some kind of list or uni-dimensional array, so that you can avoid the

```
     for ( int i = 0; i<Screen.room.block.length; i++ ) {
      for ( int j = 0; j<Screen.room.block[0].length; j++ ) {
```

and just do

```
     for ( int i = 0; i<Screen.room.blocks.length; i++ ) {
```

to check for every block and to avoid having such a big matrix when you must check every block anyway.

Another approach: you could give each block a place in a checkers-like matrix and then transform the mouse clicked event coordinates from pixels to "block" coordinates:

```
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    int x = e.getX() / widthOfABlockInPixels;
    int y = e.getY() / heightOfABlockInPixels;
    Block.click(x, y);
}
```

Say your objects are 100x100 pixels, then this would give you the right block coordinates for

```
(160, 150) => (1, 1)
(60, 50) => (0, 0)
```

and so on.

Comment: This has helped alot, ive nearly made it work as ive just clicked on 
X. 5 Y. 4
Archer clicked
but the archer is on X. 6 Y. 6, Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad I could solve your problem, don't hesitate to ask around if you stumble into another problem with making games or programming. If your question is too game-specific (AI or the like) you might have better luck in the http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ side. By the way, Welcome! :)

Comment: just a quick question, ive noticed doing it the way you have said that if the tower is on(for example) x = 6 and y = 7 and you click on location that is greater than x= 6 or y = 7 it also says tower clicked, do you know why this is so i can fix this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you need to tune the block width / height parameters. A good thing to do is pull a piece of paper and a pencil and draw the possible cases (click inside, click outside and greater coords, click outside and smaller coords ) and check if your implementation is doing right. That always helps me sort things out.

Comment: Ive fixed it,             if ( X >= i && X <= i+blockWidth &&
                 Y >= j && Y <= j+blockHeight  )
Shouldnt have the +blockWidth or + blockHeight. thanks for all the help.

Comment: By the way, you mentioned you are new to java, just in case I'll tell you you can place a break point in the code and check what's happening int "real-time" using the Debug mode. That's a good way of figuring out what the program is doing.

Answer (score 0):

This might sound a little over-simplified, but, then again, I'm just spit-balling here.  Have you thought about implementing the message into a JOptionPane.showMessageDialog? Not sure if that would be what you're looking for.

Comment: i just want it to output a message into the consol at the moment so i can add and do different things when i click on a certain tower. But when i click on a perticular tower im not getting the message.